# Why use MutlipartMemoryStreamProvider instead of HttpContext.Current.Request in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I was just reading this question [How to setup a webapi controller for multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369529/how-to-setup-a-webapi-controller-for-multipart-form-data) and was confused as to why I would want to use the multipart StreamProvider instead of HttpContext.Current.Request when I can find everything I need in the latter, namely the .Files and .Form properties.

Why should I use one over the other?