# WebAPI Is it possible to post an IFormCollection and Object in an action?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to post an IFormCollection and Object in an action?

```
public Task CreateEMail(IFormCollection collection, [FromBody] Model model)
```

I try to make an post request to WebAPI from Angular and the request is a combination of uploaded files and a model.

Angular code:

```
let model = {title:'test', subject:'test'};
let formData = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < this.droppedFilesData.length; i++) {
    let file = this.droppedFilesData[i];
    let fileName = file.name;
    formData.append(fileName, file);
}
this.service.createEmail(formData, model); // how to implement to post formData and model
```

WebAPI Code:

```
public Task CreateEMail(IFormCollection collection, [FromBody] Model model)
{
    ...
}
```

How do I implement this WebAPI?

Update: I am thinking about adding everything into FormCollection but that would be really bad code to parse data

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: yes, I added more code. I don't have any ideas to implement this point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only post a single content value to a Web API Action method. Try this:

Angular code:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFiles" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" />
onSelectFile(event: any) {
        const fi = event.srcElement;
        if (fi.files && fi.files[0]) {
            const fileToUpload = fi.files[0];
            const formData = new FormData();
            const model = new Model('name', 'email@gmail.com');
            formData.append(fileToUpload.name, fileToUpload);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(model));
            formData.append('model', JSON.stringify(model));
            this.http.post(this.requestUploadURL, formData).subscribe();
        }
}
```

Web Api Code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
{
     var formFile = Request.Form.Files?.FirstOrDefault();
     var canParse = Request.Form.TryGetValue("model", out var model);
     if (canParse)
     {
          var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(model.ToString());
     }

     return Ok();
}
```

Furthermore, you can use custom parameter binding such as JObject, FormDataCollection or Query String.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: yes, i know this, but do we have any way to separate form & model?