# How to send multipart/form-data to ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to send a image and text fields to an API endpoint but I'm received

> Unsupported content type 'multipart/form-data;
> boundary=---------------------------81801171514357

This is a ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API. I have this:

```
[HttpPost("/api/account"), Authorize]
public void SaveUser(UserModel info)
```

And my model:

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "avatar")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then I use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("avatar", imageFile);
    formData.append("name", name);
    axios.post("/api/account", formData);
```

I expected this method to run, not throw an exception. But how? I have tried to add:

```
[Consumes("application/json", "multipart/form-data")]
```

But no success.

Then I tried:

```
[HttpPost("/api/account"), Authorize]
public void SaveUser([FromForm]UserModel info)
```

The method runs, but the properties is empty on info object :(

**UPDATE:**
Solution, don't use JsonProperty PropertyName. Use the variable name.

Comment: You should use `public void SaveUser(IFormCollection collection)` when uploading a file with detail. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825794/webapi-is-it-possible-to-post-an-iformcollection-and-object-in-an-action

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with your current code, it wokrs correctly.

Comment: I have another method:
[HttpPost("/api/avatar"), Authorize]
public void SaveAvatar(IFormFile  avatar)

There is no problem. But when i add IFormFile  and properties in a model, then i get "Unsupported content type 'multipart/form-data".

Comment: Now, i found that i cant use the JsonProperty name, i must use Avatar and Name (the property names). Then it works fine. Is that possible to set the name of the properties?

Comment: This is the solution.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275185/file-upload-in-api-in-dotnet-core-wpf-windows-app][1]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Maybe you should try decorate controller input and model with `[FromForm]` attribute?
See more info here: [web api parameters binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#binding-source-parameter-inference).

In given example your controller action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost("/api/account"), Authorize]
public void SaveUser([FromForm]UserModel info)
```

In model:

```
[FromForm(Name="avatar")]
public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }

[FromForm(Name="name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes, i have try to add, [FromForm] then all the properties in my model is null.

Comment: Try to add this attribute on model properties.

Comment: i found that i cant use the JsonProperty name, i must use Avatar and Name (the property names). Then it works fine. Is that possible to set the name of the properties?

Comment: Use should use [FromForm] attribute in Controller action and in model definition. At least that worked to me.

Comment: This just saved my day! I was up all night with this issue. Thank you so much @joostas

Comment: @joostas: I have a list in my model with other types and it is working for everything except list type.  I'm sending it by using JSON.Stringify from UI. Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 3):

1-send multi part file

```
            [HttpPost, Route("postimagenews")]
            public IActionResult PostImageNews([FromForm] IFormFile file)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                    {
                        return BadRequest("Please send a photo");
                    }
                    //create unique name for file
                    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    
                    //set file url
                    var savePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/news", fileName);
    
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }
    
                    return Ok(fileName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return BadRequest("error in upload image");
                }
            }
```

2-recive multi part file

```
            public static async Task<string> PostImage(string apiendpoint, IFormFile data)
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(GetFileArray(data));
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
                    multipartContent.Add(fileContent, "file",data.FileName);
                    var resultUploadImage= await httpClient.PostAsync(apiendpoint, multipartContent);
                    if (resultUploadImage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var fileName=(await resultUploadImage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Replace("\"", "");
                        return fileName;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }
    
            public static byte[] GetFileArray(IFormFile file)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
```

3-send file multi part with postman

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Here is a working example for what you are looking for

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFile([FromForm] IFormFile file) {
  // Your code here
}
```

And inside your model:

```
public IFormFile File { get; set; }
```

Change `async Task<IActionResult>` if you don't need it...