# Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider - clientId and clientSecret coming null while trying to generate token from Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am using OWIN security for my asp.net web api 2 application and here is my startup class setting for auth.

```
 public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new CustomAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
```

And here is `CustomAuthorizationServerProvider` class implementation,

```
public class CustomAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.TryGetFormCredentials(out var clientId, out var clientSecret);

        if (clientId == "987459827985" && clientSecret == "lkfjldsfjkld")
        {
            context.Validated(clientId);
        }

        return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);
    }

    public override Task GrantClientCredentials(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TestClient"));
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        context.Validated(ticket);
        return base.GrantClientCredentials(context);
    }
}
```

Now, while trying to generate token using endpoint `http://localhost:8080/token`, I am getting NULL for both clientId and clientSecret and hence I am getting `"error": "invalid_client"`. What I am missing here?

[image]

[image]

**Edit: EDIT**

When I am using `raw` as body, I can see token generation is working and both client and secret have value. Why it is not working for `form-data`?

[image]

Comment: Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID. please see this link :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187872/Token-Based-Authentication-for-Web-API-where-Legac

Comment: but I am using Client Credential flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the postman documentation: [Sending API requests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/)

Most importantly this:

> Website forms often send data to APIs as multipart/form-data. You can replicate this in Postman using the form-data Body tab. Form data allows you to send key-value pairs, and specify the content type.

With a quick search around the web, there needs to be a special type of handling for the APIs to bind the `multipart/form-data`

i.e. [How to set up a Web API controller for multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369529/how-to-set-up-a-web-api-controller-for-multipart-form-data)

[There is even a plugin for that](https://github.com/redplane/ApiMultipartFormFormatter)

Content type is important.