# SimpleMDE/EasyMDE upload image with Blazor

Tags: c#, markdown, blazor

[SimpleMDE](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor) and [EasyMDE](https://easy-markdown-editor.tk/) are 2 JavaScript editor for Markdown. EasyMDE is an extension of SimpleMDE. I want to use EasyMDE in my Blazor project.

The implementation is quite completed and you find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor/tree/Using-EasyMDE).

This editor has the feature to upload an image or paste an image. The property `ImageUploadEndpoint` defines where the image has to be upload. And here the problem is. I can't write a ASP.NET Core Controller to receive the image as save it.

In the repository of EasyMDE there is an example in Python. First, I have to create the editor

We need to specify the server address where the images will be sent with the imageUploadEndpoint option:

```
var easyMde = new EasyMDE({
    element: document.getElementById('md-text-area'),
    hideIcons: ['image'],
    showIcons: ['upload-image'],
    imageUploadEndpoint: "https://example.com/uploadImage"
});
```

Then, the script in Python.

```
@app.route('/imageUpload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    """
    Upload an image to the server and store it to the folder defined in
    IMAGE_UPLOAD_FOLDER in flask configuration.
    Note that the image folder must be created first and with write access.
    :return: The relative path of the uploaded file, or an error among with the
    corresponding HTTP error code.
    """
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
    import os.path as op
    if 'image' not in request.files:
        return 'no_file_part', 400  # Bad request
    file = request.files['image']
    if not file.filename:
        return 'no_selected_file', 400  # Bad request
    if file and '.' in file.filename \
            and file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in 
            app.config['ALLOWED_IMAGES_TYPES']:
        file_name = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file_path = op.join(app.config['IMAGE_UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name)
        file.save(file_path)
        return file_path
    return 'no_allowed_file', 415  # Unsupported Media Type
```

I have no idea if this script is working or not. The point is how can I write a similar api in ASP.NET Core?

I wrote this API

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile files)
    {
        long size = files.Length;

        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            await files.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

but this API is not receiving any request from the EasyMDE.

Comment: Your question really just boils down to how to handle on an ASP.NET server HTTP multipart file uploads, for which there is a wealth of information on the internet.  Here's one Q/A on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369529/how-to-set-up-a-web-api-controller-for-multipart-form-data

Comment: Finally, I found a solution. I have created a Markdown Editor component for Blazor that you can find on GitHub https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor

Comment: Pasting image just doesn't work, it's bugged and broken, regardless of environment